# In Postgresql 12 how to I make the primary server a slave after a deliberate failover

Tags: postgresql, replication, failover, postgresql-12

I am using PostgreSQL 12 on Debian 10.6.
I have been reading up about replication and I have set up an asynchronous replication between one primary and standby. I wanted to test failover so I stopped the primary server and promoted the standby which was successful. I'm having difficulty finding a tutorial online about how to make the old primary a standby server now that the old standby is the new primary. What follows are the steps that I have taken, it looks like it's working but is there anything I may have missed or not thought of?

***On the new primary***

Update the pg_hba

```
echo "host    replication     replicator      <new standby ip>/24        md5" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
```

***On the new standby***

Make a back up of the lib

```
sudo mv /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/lib/postgresql/12/main.bk
```

Make a backup of the old tablespaces directory, and make a new empty directory

```
sudo mv /tablespaces /tablespaces.bk
sudo mkdir /tablespaces/
```

Make a base backup of the new primary

```
pg_basebackup -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -F p -R -c fast -l mffb -P -v -h <primary_ip> -p 5432 -U replicator
```

**If WAL Archiving is set, I'm taking these extra steps:**

*On new primary:*

```
echo "archive_mode = ON" >> /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.auto.conf
echo "archive_command = 'test ! -f  /wal_archive/%f && cp %p /wal_archive/%f'" >> /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.auto.conf
echo "restore_command = ''" >> /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.auto.conf
```

*On new standby*

```
echo "restore_command = 'cp /wal_archive/%f %p'" >> /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.auto.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds about right, but I would keep the configuration identical on both servers, so that you don't have to change anything:

- recovery settings like `restore_command` are ignored on the primary
- you can set `archive_mode` and `archive_command` on the standby, since it doesn't archive WAL anyway (unless you set `archive_mode = always`)

Before you remove the data directory and re-initialize the standby with `pg_basebackup`, you could try to run `pg_rewind`, which does the same, but faster.

Comment: May I ask why basebackup was even considered? Also pg_rewind seems not needed if the old primary was turned off cleanly? If I don't use archive_command wouldn't it be enough to just establish connection using primary_conninfo and create standby.signal file?

Comment: @sh4rkyy That only works reliably with a clean shutdown. But a failover is not a clean shutdown.